# viewDidLoad() load twice when passing data with Navigation Controller - SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to swift development. I'm trying to pass data from one UiViewController to Another UIViewController with NavigationController. I was able to pass the data, but for some reason, it loads the viewDidLoad() twice on the second UIViewController. Below is my code.

**ViewController**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var option = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

// Dine In Btn
@IBAction func dineinBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    self.option = "Dine In"
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "dinein", sender: self)

}

// Take Out Btn
@IBAction func takeoutBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    self.option = "Take Out"
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "takeout", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let vc = segue.destination as! QualityViewController
    vc.option = self.option
}

@IBAction func unwindToVC1(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) { }
}
```

**QualityViewController**

```
class QualityViewController: UIViewController {

var option = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    option += option
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

}
```

Comment: How are you determining that `viewDidLoad` gets called twice?

Comment: I ran a debugger to step through. It loaded twice and I'm looking at the simulator. It loads the view twice.

Comment: What is actually going wrong? Is something not showing correctly or something like that?

Comment: It loads the viewDidLoad(). The simulator is showing the 2nd view twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason may be that you hook buttons `dineinBtn` and `takeoutBtn` as the segue source , so the IB segue is triggered plus this

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "takeout", sender: self)
```

Another reason may be that you copied the buttons in IB so each one is hooked to 2 IBActions in code

Comment: You're right. the buttons were hooked as the segur source. Once I removed that. It worked.